# SQL question, using an aggregate function inside a made table from a query

Tags: sql

I feel like I'm not understanding how to do the syntax for this.

```
SELECT 
    main_category,
    COUNT(main_category) AS 'Kickstarters',
    CAST(SUM(if(state = 'successful', 1, 0)) AS SIGNED) AS 'Successful_Kickstarters'
FROM 
    projects
GROUP BY
    main_category;
```

Results:

```
Music           127    63
Film & Video    170    68
Theater          20    13
Art              86    41
Design           66    29
Publishing       79    24
Photography      29    12
Technology       63    24
Dance             9     6
Fashion          52    18
Food             60    22
Games            85    40
Journalism        9     4
Crafts           17     4
Comics           33    17
```

My problem is that I want to figure out the biggest number within these columns, but I don't know how to refer to them from within the query.

Comment: What is your DBMS? If you want to see the highest number on top, just use `ORDER BY`. If you only want to see the topmost row, add `FETCH FIRST`, `TOP`, `LIMIT` or whatever your DBMS offers.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for names. (But your DBMS may use non-standard backticks or brackets instead.) My recommendation is not to quote the alias names at all. `COUNT(main_category)` doesn't seem to make much sense. Either `main_category` can be null, then you get a zero count for "unknown category", or it can't, but why then the null detection? You want a mere `COUNT(*)`. `IF` is not a standard SQL function and the casting seems unnecessary. Standard SQL would be `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE state = 'successful')`. In MySQL you can use `SUM(state = 'successful')`.

Comment: Please show the results you want.  Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT main_category
      ,MAX(Kickstarters)
      ,MAX(Sucessful_Kickstarters)
      ,MAX(if(Kickstarters > Sucessful_Kickstarters, Kickstarters, Sucessful_Kickstarters))
FROM
(
    SELECT main_category
          ,COUNT(main_category) AS 'Kickstarters'
          ,CAST(SUM(if(state = 'successful', 1, 0 ) )AS SIGNED) AS 'Sucessful_Kickstarters'        
    FROM projects
    GROUP BY main_category
) DS
GROUP BY main_category
```